# 1950 book series about human brains transferred into robots so that the Galaxy could be explored

Tags: story-identification, books, space

I read this book series around 1950; I think there were only 2 books in the series. Scientists' brains are transferred into a space-exploring robots which would last for thousands of years. When the robots finally failed mechanically, the human brains would be transferred to new robots, allowing the scientists to live for tens of thousands of years and continue exploring the Galaxy.

Comment: When you say short book series do you mean a series of short books or a book series that is short?

Comment: I think they were just a couple normal length books in this series.

Comment: Was the scientist called Professor Jameson?

Comment: Prof. Jameson was my first thought as well.

Comment: I've edited the title including the year, to differentiate with other similar stories - e.g. the *Bobiverse* series from Dennis E. Taylor, which is recent.

Comment: Yes that sounds very familiar.

Comment: Oh that's it, thanks everyone so much. I've been searching for this information for a couple decades.

Answer (score 3):

This is a story that has many similarities with [the cycle of Professor Jameson, by Neil R. Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_R._Jones), which was very popular in the magazine "Amazing Stories" in the 1930s and 1940s and could, perhaps, be edited as books in the 1950s.

In the first of these stories, Professor Jameson was a dying man who had his body preserved inside a satellite orbiting the Earth. Millions of years later his body is found by an extraterrestrial expedition of Zoromes.

The Zoromes were originally organic beings and reached immortality by transplanting their brains into autonomous machines. When they find Jameson's body, they do the same with his brain, bringing him back to life and inviting him to join their eternal exploration of the Galaxy.

[image: "The Music-Monsters" is a "Professor Jameson" story that takes the cover of the April 1938 issue of "Amazing Stories". You can see here an artificial body of a Zorome, or can it be Jameson's?]

Neil R. Jones wrote more than 30 stories about Professor Jameson and his companions. I see in wikipedia that they were compiled into books in the 1960s. Here are the covers from then in case they bring back any memories of you.

[image: The Planet of the Double Sun, Ace Books]

I don't know if there are any previous editions. I only have read the first story of all, "The Jameson Satellite", which was included in [an anthology by Isaac Asimov.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Before_the_Golden_Age)

[image: Before the Golden Age]

Comment: "The Jameson Satellite" is available at project Gutenberg: http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/26906

Answer (score 2):

There is an Outer Limits episode, [The Brain of Colonel Barham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brain_of_Colonel_Barham) with a similar plot. I think there were also several other episodes of that series with a roughly parallel theme. It could be that the story you seek was adapted to TV in one of those episodes.

Comment: Partial answers are valid. :)